# Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, selinux

When I want to restart the httpd searvice on centOS 6.7 I have the following error:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

This is error_log:

```
ls -Z /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
```

I disabled selinux also.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

`httpd` probably runs as user `apache` or user `httpd`. Your log is owned and only writable by `root`. Change ownership of your log file to make this work.

This should do the trick:

```
~# chown apache:apache /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
```

Comment: chown: apache.apache: illegal user name

Answer (score 4):

In my case i have done below actions post that able to start the httpd service without any error.

Error:

```
# sudo tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
Sep 27 09:09:19 MASTERREPOWEB systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 27 09:09:20 MASTERREPOWEB httpd[33693]: (13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
Sep 27 09:09:20 MASTERREPOWEB httpd[33693]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Sep 27 09:09:20 MASTERREPOWEB systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Solution:

```
ls -lZ /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
sudo chcon -Rv system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 /etc/httpd/logs/
sudo systemctl restart httpd
sudo systemctl status httpd
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you want to keep SELinux active

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should change the group of that forder to apache,  it's not recommended to have root as owner of server stuff. Anyway apache should change that on his own after http starts...

From [httpd Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions):

> Before we start, we need to be aware that the Apache HTTP server
>   (httpd) runs as a particular user and group.
>
> On Linux as well as most other Unix-like systems, httpd is started as
>   the "root" user; UID=root, GID=root. This is necessary because only
>   this user can bind to port 80 and 443 (anything below 1024 in fact).
>
> After http starts and binds to its ports (defined by the Listen
>    statments in httpd.conf), it changes user to that specified in
>    httpd.conf. Typically:
>
> User: apache
>   Group: apache
>
> Note that Debian based systems, including
>   Ubuntu, use "www-data" instead.

As a possible solution you should add yourself into the group apache

```
usermod -a -G apache (username)
```

Then:

```
chgrp apache (folderPath)
chmod g+rwxs (folderPath)
```

Anyway that's weird... tell me if this solved your issue, if it didn't I will edit it as long as you provide me further information :)

Comment: This is centOs so I think we don't have `www-data`.

Comment: @MLSC Then change www-data for apache as mentioned in the httpd wiki fragment

Answer (score 1):

If you are on **RedHat/Fedora/CentOS/RockyLinux** then try to execute the following command (`14:00` is your time since the error happened):

```
journalctl -t setroubleshoot --since=14:00
```

You could see the following errors:

```
Jun 25 14:21:33 fedora setroubleshoot[1609]: SELinux is preventing httpd from open access on the file /var/log/gitea/error_log. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 5e2bf467-e935-4fa7-a7fd-d0f7f257828e
Jun 25 14:21:33 fedora setroubleshoot[1609]: SELinux is preventing httpd from open access on the file /var/log/gitea/error_log.

                                             *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                             If you believe that httpd should be allowed open access on the error_log file by default.
                                             Then you should report this as a bug.
                                             You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                             Do
                                             allow this access for now by executing:
                                             # ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
                                             # semodule -X 300 -i my-httpd.pp
```

It means the lack of permissions is not related to `chmod`, but rather to `SELinux`.

In order to fix the issue you need to execute the following command (please adjust the log directory accordinly):

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/log/gitea(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv '/var/log/gitea/'
systemctl restart httpd
```

The error should disappear. And please never switch off the `SELinux` permanently (as someone might suggest) because your server could be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7

Try disabling SElinux and then reboot then

systemctl restart httpd

Note: never leave SElinux disabled. If the problem is solved then enable(enforce) it and then enable httpd in SElinux

https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/

Answer (score -7):

Just run it as super user:

```
service httpd start
```

> Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
>
> Unable to open logs   [FAILED]

```
sudo service httpd start
```

> Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]

Comment: Please no, don't run apache as root, this solves the described problem but is a security risk and would be worse